# How to run code only after all other code is finished?

Tags: ios, swift

Kind of a silly question, wrote a whole app and still dont know this...
Right now I have a "delete account button" where it deletes all the user's posts and performs a segue back to the login screen but it seems that not all the posts are being deleted because it performs the segue before completion.

Is there a way I can perform a segue only when it is done deleting the user's post? As in, run the segue LAST.

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    if buttonIndex == 1 { // Post One Pic
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("postimage1segue", sender: self)
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    PFObject.deleteAllInBackground(objects)
                }
            }
        })

        var query1 = PFQuery(className: "PrivatePost")
        query1.whereKey("userId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query1.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    PFObject.deleteAllInBackground(objects)
                }
            }
        })

        PFUser.currentUser().deleteInBackground()
        performSegueWithIdentifier("accountdeletedsegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: First, it would be really helpful if you posted your code

Comment: Where are you doing your deletions? Are you manually initiating the segue, or are you using `viewWillDisappear`? Or both?

Comment: i added the code, it is cut off so u want to scroll down in the code box. Also do you know anything about parse? when deleting a account do i need to PFUser.logOut()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if PFUser has a deleteInBackgroundWithBlock: method or not but you can also use Grand Central Dispatch too.

Here is an example in Obj-C:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t bg_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_group_async(group, bg_queue, ^{
    // do something 
});

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //when done do something else on main
});
```

EDIT: Swift GCD Groups

```
var downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create()
dispatch_group_enter(group)

// Do something

dispatch_group_leave(group)

dispatch_group_notify(group, GlobalMainQueue) {
    //when something is done do something else on main queue
}
```